# Keep field up to date, with occurence of field in other collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm quite new to mongodb and can't figure out how to make the value of a field the result of a certain function on another field. To give an example:

collection `names`:

```
{ "name1" : "a", "name2" : "b"}
{ "name1" : "c", "name2" : "a"}
```

collection `occurrences`:

```
{ "name" : "a", "occurrences" : <function on names>}
{ "name" : "b", "occurrences" : <function on names>}
{ "name" : "c", "occurrences" : <function on names>}
```

My goal is to have the field `occurrences` representing the times the certain name occurs in the collection `names`, e.g. `{"name": "a", "occurrences":2}`.

I looked through the documentation and found the function `$count`, but I can't see how to implement it in a field instead of a call to the database.

Thank you for your help!